# Why need WizardStep objects be represented as …?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

This is probably a stupid question, but still..

A *Wizard* control is made up of a collection of *WizardStep* objects that represent single steps of a wizard. But why are these W*izardStep* object represented as controls ( thus they require *runat=Server* attribute )?Couldn’t they be handled similarly to *ListItem* objects, which don’t require *runat* attribute, but are instead accessed via *Parent_Control.Item* property?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

WizardStep controls can be containers for other controls, which makes them non-trivial. Whereas ListItems are just simple obects made up of a string and an ID and not much else.

Comment: What do you mean by non-trivial?